# c program SWIG to python gives 'ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function'

Tags: python, c, debian, swig

I am trying to use .c program in python script with SWIG. To start with, I installed SWIG and trying simple example from tutorial [swig webpage](http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html).

I am using Raspberry Pi with Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.4 (stretch)

This is what I do:
1. `swig -python example.i` - great, this created two new files: 'example.py' and 'example_wrap.c'
2. `gcc -fpic -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c example_wrap.c` - this creates 'example_wrap.o' file
3. compile example.c in Geany; this gives 'example.o' file
4. `gcc -shared example.o example_wrap.o -o example.so` - now a new file 'example.so' is created.
Time to try it:

```
python
```

I am using Python 2.7.13 here

```
>>>import example
```

And this gives traceback:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (initexample)
```

How to sort this problem out?

Comment: `gcc -shared example.o example_wrap.o -o _example.so`.

Comment: @CrisFati your solution works partially: when I do 'import example' in python interpreter it doesn't give traceback, but doing later for example fract(4) it says: 'NameError: name 'fact' is not defined.' Anyway, when I do start python this way: 'python -i example.py' I don't have to import anything and fact(4) gives proper answer of 24. What is the problem now?

Comment: `example.fact(4)` (*DOT* **not** *SPACE*). And the name is `fact` (your comment also mentions `fract`).

Comment: Great! You can make it an answer. With second comment as well. It is an important bit to this subject.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what happens for a dynamic *Python* module (at least, in current *swig* version):

- The module name (let's stick with *example*, like in the tutorial) is specified in the *.i* file: `%module example`
- At build time, 2 files are generated:

  - ***_**${MODULE_NAME}.so*: a dynamic module or shared object having the name the module name preceded by an *UnderScore*, in our example ***_**example.so*, which contain the actual *C* compiled code
  - *${MODULE_NAME}.py*: which is a wrapper over the previous one; *example.py* - this is the module "entry point"

A *Python* dynamic module must export an ***init**** function (***PyInit_** in *Python 3***) as explained on [[Python 2.Docs]: The Module’s Method Table and Initialization Function](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html#the-module-s-method-table-and-initialization-function), and more: what comes after the *init* part, **must match module (*.so*) name** (in our case it's ***init_example***).

By naming the dynamic module *example.so*, when *Python* tried to load it, it searched for *initexample* which (obviously) didn't exist, raising *ImportError*.

Changing the module name to ***_example.so*** (`gcc -shared example.o example_wrap.o -o _example.so`), as the *URL* also instructs, no longer raises an exception.

Then, the functions are available like this:

> ```py
> >>> import example  # This imports example.py which automatically imports _example.so
> >>> example.fact(4), example.my_mod(7, 2), example.get_time()
> ```

Might also want to check:

- [[SO]: How to solve Python-C-API error "This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip."? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75307579/4788546)

Answer (score 0):

Like CristiFati said *"gcc -shared example.o example_wrap.o -o _example.so"*

The naming is wrong and causing the error.