# Is a c++ complier needed for the installation of Locust 2.15.1 and is it compatible with python version 3.10.9?

Tags: python, locust

When trying to install locust I'm getting this error

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

Encountered error while trying to install package.

greenlet

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.0.1
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
exit code: 1

See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.0.1
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Its asking me to get Microsoft C++ Build Tools but do i need a c++ complier for Locust version 2.15.1? I previously was able to install locust version 2.14.2 and I never got that error and I didn't have to install Microsoft C++ Build Tools. Just wondering if its needed for this newer locust version? The python version I'm currently using is 3.10.9.

I'm expecting this to install without failing.

Comment: Seems that the error comes from a different package (dependency). https://stackoverflow.com/a/75307579/4788546, https://stackoverflow.com/a/73805010/4788546, https://stackoverflow.com/a/75150938/4788546, https://stackoverflow.com/a/57883242/4788546 might provide some details (although won't contain a fix for your specific problem).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that there is no binary version of the latest release of `greenlet` for your particular OS version.

If you done want to install build tools, try `pip install --prefer-binary locust`